There's been a clarification in WordPress trademark policy
Check this out. https://web.archive.org/web/20240924024555/https://wordpressfoundation.org/trademark-policy/
It says, in part,

All other [than not-for-profit FOSS] WordPress-related businesses or projects can use the WordPress name and logo to refer to and explain their services, but they cannot use them as part of a product, project, service, domain name, or company name and they cannot use them in any way that suggests an affiliation with or endorsement by the WordPress Foundation or the WordPress open source project.

Does Stack have an exemption?

It looks like a clear violation of the policy as written. Of course, given fifteen years of tolerating such uses, this is legally meaningless and there’s no actual concern from people who were using it already.

This is likely part of the wider WordPress drama that kicked off between the founder of WordPress and a hosting company. This was one of a number of recent changes of questionable legal standing.


Does Stack have an exemption?

Not that I'm aware but only legal counsel could confirm this, it's not something a non-employee could definitively say ( unless you were Matt Mullenweg ).
I would keep in mind that this is an old stack and no issue has been taken with it yet, we also aren't profiting billions so may not be the highest target if they decide to contest that, but that's for Stack to decide.
We did get a WP logo in the header after our redesign which was removed after community feedback precisely because of trademark infringement, but this was out of concern not because the foundation had been in contact. Unfortunately no replacement header graphic was added. We also fed back that the blue used was very close to wp.com so it was changed to black.
